# Build android from source, make vs make sdk

Tags: android, android-source

I'm building Android from source code.

What is difference between `make` and `make sdk`?  Why does it clean files between this builds?

Comment: `make sdk` will probably build the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) you would use to build / compile apps with.

Comment: ok doc is saying so. but what is the actual difference?
both `make` and `make sdk` generates tools like `adb` and `emulator`, filesystems, kernel, etc

Answer (score 0):

For android applications, there are two different SDK numbers generally associated. There is the minSdk and the targetSdk, both displayed in the AndroidManifest.xml file. The targetSdk is the API level that the app is created against. This is generally the API level of the device the app is particularly tested on. The minSdk, on the other hand, is just that, the minimum API level that your app can safely run against. If you set the minSdk to 8, but use a class such as Fragments, an error will occur on any device running API 8, 9 or 10 because Fragments weren't introduced until API 11 (3.0 Honeycomb). The app also cannot be installed on any device with an API lower than the specified minSdk.